# How app supports casting 4k content to TV over limited wifi bandwidth

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, screencasts

Sending uncompressed 4k 30 Hz video(like pc connecting to monitor) requires around 1.58 Gbit/s of bandwidth. So I got curious then how I am able to stream 4k Youtube videos over 50 Mbps wifi network in my phone, I learned here that here Youtube uses some compression so it is able to stream 4k content over wifi.
Now there is also screencast option in phones to cast content to TV over chromecast/miracast. Here since the frames are sent from phone to TV on realtime so there does not look any scope for compression, now we should again need 1.58 Gbit/s bandwidth which is not possible on wifi. But it actually works, so how is it happening ?

Answer (score 2):

> Sending uncompressed 4k 30 Hz video(like pc connecting to monitor) requires around 1.58 Gbit/s of bandwidth.

It's actually more like 6 Gbps, depending on color depth, SDR/HDR, etc: 3840 pixels × 2160 lines × 30 frames × 24 bit ≅ 5.9 Gbps.

> But it actually works, so how is it happening ?

By compressing it. [Miracast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast), which is the most widely used protocol, uses [H.264](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding) (mandatory) or [H.265](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) (optional). Note also that Miracast only requires support for HD, support for 4K is optional.

You can usually see (and feel) the noticeable delay caused by this compression, especially if you see the two screens next to each other.